# Как Node js получить переменную по названию

Tags: javascript

Как в Node js подставить вместо name -> this.id

```
class st {
    constructor() {
        this.id = 0;
    }
    set(name, _val) {
        name = _val;
    }
}

st.set("id", "10");
```

Answer (score -1):

Наверное так:

```
this[name] = _val;
```